# OpenJPA 2.4.0 couldn't handle Oracle NVARCHAR data types

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, openjpa

I am having issue with OpenJPA version 2.4.0 integrating with `NVARCHAR` Oracle data type.

In one of the Entity of my application i have to associate property to an underlying table having oracle column type as `NVARCHAR2`. When I tried to use this entity inside JPA query it comes back with an error message.

```
[<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "com.xxxxxx.xxxxName" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "varchar". Column details: 
Full Name: XXXXXX.XXXX_NAME 
Type: unknown(-9) 
Size: 65 
Default: null 
Not Null: false
```

When I searched for this issue it looks like this issue was present in older openJPA versions and was resolved already.

Please suggest if anybody know the fix.

Comment: Updated Error message: [<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "com.xxxxxx.xxxxName" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "varchar". Column details: 
Full Name: XXXXXX.xxxx_NAME 
Type: unknown(-9) 
Size: 65 
Default: null 
Not Null: false

Comment: so openjpa doesn't support that JDBC type, and ? get the openjpa code and contribute support for it

Comment: Hi Billy, I could do that. However, since we are having this issue during a project migration activity we may not have much time to resolve this. Hence, wanted to know if anybody already found this issue and have for this fix already.